# ServerSocket accept() method

Tags: java

Who knows how the port is chosen when I'm using accept method of ServerSocket class? Is it possible to define a range for the ports the method can choose from? Can I 'take' ports one by one just in order?

```
ServerSocket sSocket = new ServerSocket(5050);
Socket socket = sSocket.accept();
```

[image: From the book]

Comment: try getLocalPort and see if that is true.

Comment: Is it a good book that you are reading? "plain old socket" sounds weird to me.

Comment: Yes, it is Head First Java, a book for beginners.

Comment: I think that that image is at least confusing, if not totally wrong.

Comment: Did it used to work that way?  It's funny that I thought it worked that way, too.  One more reason why I don't care much for the "Head First" series.

Comment: Still I think the "Head First" is the best for beginners.

Comment: The picture is wrong. The accepted socket has the same local port number as the listening socket.

Comment: @Eugene Not if it contains misinformation like this.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The diagram is incorrect (and is listed in the [unconfirmed errata](https://oreilly.com/catalog/errataunconfirmed.csp?isbn=9780596009205) on the O'Reilly site).

The *client* chooses *its* port at random (you don't need to do anything special in Java) and connects to the server on whichever port you specified. Using the `netstat` commandline tool you can see this.

First, just the listening server socket with no clients:

```
simon@lucifer:~$ netstat -n -a
Active Internet connections (including servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address     (state)
...
tcp46      0      0  *.5050                 *.*                 LISTEN
...
```

(there are lots of other entries, I've just removed the unrelated ones)

Now with one client connecting from localhost (127.0.0.1):

```
simon@lucifer:~$ netstat -n -a
Active Internet connections (including servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address     (state)
...
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.64895        127.0.0.1.5050      ESTABLISHED <- 1
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.5050         127.0.0.1.64895     ESTABLISHED <- 2
tcp46      0      0  *.5050                 *.*                 LISTEN      <- 3
...
```

Since the client is connecting from the same machine, we see two established connections - one from client to server (1), the other from server to client (2). They have opposite local and foreign addresses (since they're talking to each other) and you can see the server is still using port 5050 while the original server socket (3) continues to listen on the same port.

(this output is from a Mac, but Windows/Linux also have `netstat` giving similar output)

Comment: Hi SimonJ, could you please explain why the server side could use the same socket port ? thanks !

Comment: @MrROY Because the client chooses its local port at random, as he says in the answer.

Comment: @EJP Client chooses its local port is fine. but question is server is ESTABLISHED on 5050 and in other entry still listening on same port 5050. Why it uses the same socket port?

Comment: @chs_Infinity I'm not sure what you're asking. The server socket continues using port 5050 so that new clients can connect to it. The new connection uses port 5050 on the server-side because that's how the protocol was defined.

The reason it's _possible_ is that the "identity" of a connection is based on the 5-tuple: (source IP, source port, destination IP, destination port, protocol (tcp or udp)). Changing one field (usually source port) is enough to yield a new, distinct connection.

Answer (score 7):

*You* chose the port, when you said new ServerSocket(5050). All that stuff about using a different port for the accepted socket is 100% BS.

Answer (score 3):

A TCP connection consists of four parts:

- Client IP
- Client Port
- Server IP
- Server Port

There can be, for example, multiple clients connected to the same server port - as long as the clients don't have the same IP **and** the same prt, it's ok. And for that part, the Operating System takes care.

So it's totally ok to listen just on one port.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. I just uploaded an image from the book, can you have a look please?

Answer (score 0):

The [ServerSocket](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) defines the port as part of the constructor.
If you do not specify a port, the socket is not bound (i.e. cannot be accessed).

To get the port of the connecting Socket, use getPort() and not getLocalPort(). The second one will give you the port on your server.

Comment: I've added a note to my question. Please have a look on the second line. Thanks

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean. 100 sockets connected to your server will all connect via port 5050. If you mean the port of the machine that is connecting to you, then use getPort().

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `0` as a port number to create a server socket on any free port, or make a method like this to create a server socket for any free port in the given range:

```
public java.net.ServerSocket createServerSocket(int rangeStart, int rangeEnd)
                            throws java.io.IOException {
  for(int port=rangeStart; port<=randeEnd; port++) {  
    try {
      return new ServerSocket(port);
    } catch(java.net.BindException be) {
      // debug/warning here
      continue;
    }
  }
  throw new java.io.IOException("Failed to create a server socket, all ports between " +
                                rangeStart + " - " + rangeEnd + " are already in use.");
}
```

The loop doesn't take care of another exception (`SecurityException` for example), but you can add it.

Comment: ServerSocket(i)? Did you mean: ServerSocket(port)?

Comment: Won't this not work, because when it first returns the ServerSocket, it stops the function?