# SeverSocket stops accepting

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I'm working on a game with a event based structure with the main game logic hosted on a server; currently it's a very small featureset that only allows to host one game between exactly two participants. I've read on various questions about `ServerSocket` and none of them answers my question. I already took a look at

- [ServerSocket accept continues to block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392141/serversocket-accept-continues-to-block)
- [ServerSocket.accept()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664235/serversocket-accept)
- [Java ServerSocket won't accept new connections until close() is called on the accepted socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434773/java-serversocket-wont-accept-new-connections-until-close-is-called-on-the-ac)
- [ServerSocket accept() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307549/serversocket-accept-method)

In my project I utilize `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream`. Everything works as expected (receiving / sending both on server and client side), but after both sockets are registered, the `accept` method of the `ServerSocket` instance continues to block forever, even if the same code is invoked before. Perhaps it's an issue that appears after communicating over a socket once?

My server log shows the following:

> waiting for accept
>   accepting first socket
>   sending an event to socket1 for informing about waiting for the opponent
>   waiting for accept
>   accept second socket
>   sending responses to both sockets
>   waiting for accept (and blocking forever)

When the log says response events where sent, they were properly received and processed at the client side. The client side debug outputs show that the next event is *definitely* sent. Maybe it's about not closing the client sockets (mentioned in the third linked question)? Anyway I can't close the client sockets because further communication would be impossible.

**Client side code**

```
public void send(Event e) {
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(
                socket.getOutputStream());
        out.writeObject(e);
        out.flush();
        log.debug("sending event... "+e);
    }
    catch(IOException ioe) {
        log.fatal("constructing oos failed", ioe);
    }
}
```

**Server side code**

```
@Override
public void run() {
    running = true;
    while(running) {
        try {
            Socket s = socket.accept();
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            Event event = (Event) ois.readObject();

            try {
                Event[] response = controller.consume(event);
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(sockets[0].getOutputStream());
                oos.writeObject(response[0]);
                oos.flush();
                ObjectOutputStream oos2 = new ObjectOutputStream(sockets[1].getOutputStream());
                oos2.writeObject(response[1]);
                oos2.flush();
            }
            catch(...) {
                // multiple catch clauses for different exceptions
                // all just logging (nothing passes silently!)
            }
    }
}
```

For shortening, the method for assigning the two sockets to the `Socket[]` array was left out, but since there are **no exceptions**, keeping the socket works. Do you have any idea what could cause the described behavior? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I suggest you read the [Networking tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/index.html). Especially the [socket section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html).

Comment: I've already read the tutorial. It doesn't cover objectstreams and four lines of pseudo code on handling multiple clients aren't enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`accept`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept%28%29) method only accepts *new* connections. Since you only have two clients attempting to connect to your server, it will hang indefinitely on your third invocation of `accept`.

Side note: You don't need to continuously create new `ObjectInputStream`s and `ObjectOutputStream`s. You can just create one of each for each `Socket` and keep references to them for reuse.

Comment: Good hint. So structural aspects have to be changed. What would be your approach to handle both behavior, registering new connections and maintaining the existing ones?

Comment: Multiple threads, or use [non-blocking IO](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-javaio/).